# Why is my computer creating a D drive when I run multiplayer pixel streaming?

Tags: windows, streaming, 3d

I tried multiplayer pixel streaming with Unreal Engine but it failed. When I open a different port and connect to the local host, the following message appears. As a result of checking this problem, this message appears because textures cannot be imported from D3D11 and CUDA. The problem is, I don't have a D drive.
This problem seems to be caused by communicating with the WebRtc module.

[image]

Comment: That's a reference to the source file where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This error message contains the original path where the software source code resided when it was built. This is not a path on your computer, unless you built Unreal Engine yourself.

This message is not about texture importing or anything like that. Instead, it means the H264 encoder was set up incorrectly. This could be the result of the engine failing to initialize altogether.

Comment: Thanks Man. Thanks your kindness. How can i solve this problem? I use UE 4.27

Comment: This bug occurs when using 2 clients and 2 signal servers. Whether or not matchmaking was used was irrelevant.

Comment: I cannot help you solve the original problem, sorry. Furthermore, there’s just not enough information: What game are you trying to run, how are you running it, how exactly does streaming come into play, …. You’ll have better luck in a community that specialized in Unreal Engine or game development. There’s [gamedev.se], but I’m not sure whether such a question would be on-topic there.

Comment: Game Development closed my Question...